# eclipse Android SDK Update loses ADT update, and SDK location

Tags: android, sdk, adt, failed-installation

Been away from eclipse and Android for three months, came back to get back into it.

Tried to install two new updates to the `SDK (v16 of one thing, v20 of another)`, which of course failed because I forgot to run eclipse as Administrator, so I got the '`folder failed to be moved' error.` 
Fine, do it again, seems to finish. Reminds at the end to check eclipse/help/'check for updates', so I did, and let it run while I had dinner. 
Now, I'm ready to jump back in.

1. When I open eclipse, I get the pop-up `"This Android SDK requires Android Development Toolkit version 20.0 or above. Current version is 16.0.1.201112150204-238534. Please update ADT to the latest version."`
2. Clicking eclipse / window / Android SDK Manager (where I originally found and authorized these updates), I now get "Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in preferences"
3. I get the same error as in #2 when I click on AVD Manager on the same menu.

In reviewing some answers here, I got to the `"reinstall eclipse"` suggestion and decided to write this up and see if a more rational explanation / solution might be forthcoming.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update ADT to a newer version and setup SDK location again. This should be solve your problem.(I'm sorry my answer is most likely a comment, but unfortunately I can't make comments still)

Comment: Well, that didn't work. I've run the SDK Manager on its own (since eclipse can't find it anymore) and that ran to completion, yet showed that I still had the 'Tools' to be installed or updated, so I ran it again, and it now shows that Tools is installed at rev. 22.0.1, and Platform-tools and Build-tools (new item) are at rev 17. But eclipse still claims my SDK is at 16.0.1.xxxxxxx, and won't let me set any locations for the SDK in Preferences, even though it's already pointing where the SDK is. I have a sneaking suspicion I'm reading one of these error msgs incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

As I feared, I'd read the error msg wrong. Since the SDK manager was telling me the 'Tools' were at 22.0.xxx, I was reading this as the 'Tools' in ADT 'Android Development Tools.' It's not. Went back to the SDK web page from the SDK Read Me.txt, and from that page to the ADT Plugin page, which then led to the 'Installing the eclipse plugin'. Only difference in following those steps was that I didn't have to 'Add' ("Error: duplicate location") because the location to get the plugin was already in the dropdown for 'Work with:'.

COMMENT: Why does this have to be a separate update? Hasn't anyone looked at the SDK Manager's 'Update SDK' process, disconnected from the eclipse ADT plugin update, and thought 'Jeez, won't that create incompatabilities/confusion/difficulties among developers and prospective developers?' I'm not that level of developer in this environment (yet) but c'mon, gang, no one knows how to link the SDK update to a follow-on script to start the ADT eclipse plugin update dialog?